# estou tentando criar uma função q gera 10000 palavras aleatórias com 3 a 5 caracteres, mas so esta passando uma palavra

Tags: javascript

```
function textoAleatorio(){
    var letras = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    var aleatorio = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < 5 ; i++) {
        var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * letras.length);
        aleatorio += letras.substring(rnum, rnum + 1);

    }
    return aleatorio;
}
console.log(textoAleatorio())
```

Comment: Bom, você só está chamando a função 1 vez... Para gerar 10.000 palavras, precisaria chamá-la 10.000 vezes (dentro de um laço de repetição, obviamente).

Answer (score -4):

```
for (var j = 0; j < 10000 ; i++) { 
   console.log(textoAleatorio());
}
```

Faltou um looping assim, para chamar essa função 10000 vezes, mais ainda daria para melhorar muito a dinâmica, e otimizar todo o código...